# Creating new Columns within a select

Tags: sql, count

Utilizing the following "STUDENT" table, write a query that returns two columns: the first column is named "SMITH" and it should return the count of students with the last name "Smith;"  the second column is named "NOT_SMITH" and it should return the count of students that don't have the last name of "Smith."

This is the project I am attempting, but I cannot figure out how to complete it. I tried to look up how to complete this, but I don't know what this specific function would be called.

I know it's not correct, but here is where I started:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUDENT 
CASE
 WHEN LAST_NAME = 'SMITH' THEN "SMITH"
 WHEN LAST_NAME != 'SMITH' THEN "NOT_SMITH"
GROUP BY COUNT AS
```

While I believe that the counts will come out correct, this will not provide the columns needed.

The current columns are STUDENT_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME

Please let me know if any further information is helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional sum

```
 SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN LAST_NAME = 'SMITH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SmithCount,
        SUM( CASE WHEN LAST_NAME = 'SMITH' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as notSmithCount
 FROM Student
```

Be carefull if you want count `NULLs` as `notSmithCount`